# How to use one filter on two separate fields at the same time

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on a Tableau visualisation of network data, showing trends in user behaviour.

I have a table with users (USERS) and a table with network messages (MESSAGES): Each message has a sender and a receiver from the list of users.

I have two worksheets, one showing trends of outgoing messages and one showing incoming messages. The two worksheets are placed in the same dashboard.

How can I create a filter dropdown containing all users from USERS that filters senders in one worksheet and receivers in the second worksheet?

I have tried to duplicate the MESSAGES data source and blend USERS with two different fields, but the performance is not acceptable. Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Create a new parameter:

- data type string
- allowable values set to list
- add from field - user field

Quick filter on user-sending

- select condition tab, By formula
- [user.sending]=[user.parameter]

Repeat for user-receiving sheet.

Lastly, right-click user.parameter and select 'add to sheet' (or add it to you dashboard).

Comment: Many thanks for the response. The potential downside to that solution is that the parameter does not get refreshed automatically as new users come onboard. Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: Yeah, that is an issue with Tableau, no option for dynamic parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by selecting the 'use all' option rather than using a range or a list. This works very well for dates especially as it shows a calendar and then you can pick the date you want to see.